# Getting two values as array

Tags: php, arrays, date

This is a simple code. But i don't have much idea in array topic. I want to make two year as key value. Here is my code.

```
$year = date("Y");
$previousyear = $year -1;
$arr=[];
array_push($arr,$year);
array_push($arr,$previousyear);
print_r($arr);
```

I am getting output like this.

```
Array ( [0] => 2016 [1] => 2015 )
```

But i need two years as key value of an array. Is there any other ways to get years as key values. Please help me.

Thanks!!

Comment: `I want to make two year as key value. Here is my code.` What do mean by this ?

Comment: What is your expected output. Post that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

array_push pushes only values, not keys. Also you have to give a value when you set a key into an array. Try this.

```
$year = date('Y');

$arr = [];

$arr[$year] = 'year';

$arr[$year-1] = 'previous year';
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. I tried this. It shows the error "Array to string conversion -- at line 10" @Mehmet

Answer (score 0):

[array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) pushes the value in an array, it increments the counter of the key from 0,1,2 etc..

If you want year as a key you can do it as follow:

```
<?php
$year = date('Y');
$arr = [];
$arr[$year] = 'Current Year';
$year=$year-1;
$arr[$year] = 'Previous year'; 
print_r($arr);
?>
```

https://eval.in/587219

Above code will add values to array with key.